# How do I ensure that real numbers in a list are at least 'y' apart

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a bunch of data (x,y), which I want to cluster (say 60 points). However, due to the nature of the data, some clusters can be very small (1-2 points), while other clusters can contain many points(5-6). Running a k-means algo results in non-unique centroid values due to the inherent random starting point. I do know that the centers of each cluster should be at least 'y' apart from each other in the y direction. (x is relatively unimportant) So after running my kmeans, if any 2 clusters' center is within 'y', I would like to re-run the kmeans algo till it obtains my criteria. Also, if there no convergence is had, the number of clusters can be slowly reduced.

How do I go about doing it in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't really make sense: is `y` a variable, or the minimum distance between clusters in a given dimension?

That said, here's a stab at it. The centers of the clusters are in the component `$centers` of your k-means fit. So you can repeat the procedure until you get a fit where the centers are at least a given distance apart in the `y`th dimension.

```
repeat {
    m <- kmeans(df, k)
    cy <- m$centers[, 2]
    cy_diff <- diff(sort(cy))
    if(all(cy_diff > min_dist)) break
}
```

Replace `df`, `k`, and `min_dist` as appropriate for your data. This is all rather statistically dubious IMO, but that's a question for CrossValidated.

Comment: y will be a user input value that enforces the centroids to always be spaced out in the y direction by the value y. Thanks, that snippet solved my problem.